# Automorphism of ring $R$ implying automorphism of $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Assume $\phi:R\to R$ is an automorphism of a commutative ring $R$. Recall that an $R$-module is an abelian group $M$ on which $R$ acts linearly. We denote the action by $(r,m)\mapsto r\cdot m$.

On the other hand, the automorphism $\phi$ gives another $R$-module structure on the same abelian group $M$:
$$
(r,m)\mapsto \phi(r)\cdot m
$$
Let's denote this by $M_\phi$. In general, this $M_\phi$ is **not** isomorphic to $M$ as $R$-modules. Nevertheless, I am interested in exploring the conditions under which the relationship $M_\phi \cong M$ actually holds true.

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748594/can-a-ring-isomorphism-change-the-structure-of-a-module) post, it suggests that such an isomorphism exists when $M$ is free. But, are there more general results, especially when considering conditions like $R$ being Noetherian or $M$ being finitely generated?

Comment: The counter-example given in the answer to the post you link to doesn't make your proposed conditions look very promising: it has $R$ Noetherian and $M$ finitely generated.

Comment: Another thought -- generally, for $M$ to be isomorphic to $M_\phi$, you need a map to begin with. In the case that $M$ is free, you get a map by sending free basis elements to free basis elements. But, if $M$ is not free, there doesn't seem to be anything like a "natural" map from $M$ to $M_\phi$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring and $\phi\in \mathrm{Aut}(R)$ an automorphism of $R$.

*Definition*:
The automorphism $\phi$ induces an  endofunctor from $R$-mod, the category of (left) R-modules  is an induced action of $\phi$ on the category of (left) $R$-modules: If $M$ is a left $R$-module then $M$ is an abelian group equipped with a homorphism $a\colon R\to \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb Z}(R)$ from $R$ to the ring of endomorphisms of the additive group of $M$. We may thus use $\phi$ to construct a new $R$-module structure on $M$, with action $a\circ \phi$, where we will write $M_\phi$ to indicate $M$ is being viewed as an $R$-module via this new action. Note that if $M_1, M_2$ are $R$-modules then $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M_1,M_2) = \mathrm{Hom}_R(M_{1,\phi}, M_{2,\phi})$, *i.e.* the action of $()_{\phi}$ on morphisms is trivial.

***Question***: Are their natural conditions which ensure that an $R$-module $M$ satisfies $M\cong M_\phi$ (or $M \ncong M_{\phi}$)?

Note that an isomorphism $T\colon M \to M_{\phi}$ is, in concrete terms, an automorphism of the underlying abelian group given by $M$ which satisfies

\begin{equation}
\label{twisting isomorphism}
T(rm) = \phi(r)T(m), \quad \forall \in R, m\in M.
\end{equation}

Moreover, if $M\cong M_{\phi}$ then space $\{\phi\colon M \to M_{\phi}: \phi \text{ an isomorphism}\}$ is acted by $\text{Aut}_R(M)$ on the right and $\text{Aut}_R(M_{\phi})$ on the left, and each action is simply-transitive  (since this is true for any two isomorphic $R$-modules). may be large, and so, at least on the face of it, there will not be a "canonical" choice of such an isomorphism.

*Example 1*: One simple (but restrictive) answer to our question is that a sufficient condition for $M\cong M_{\phi}$ is for $M$ to be a free $R$-module: if $B$ is a basis of $M$ then it is easy to see that $B$ is a basis of $M_{\phi}$. But then the identity map from $B$ to itself extends uniquely to an isomorphism $T_B\colon M \to M_{\phi}$. More concretely if $S\subseteq B$ is finite and $m = \sum_{b\in S} c_b.b$ then $T_B(m): = \sum_{b \in S}\phi(c_b).b$.

**A sufficient condition for $M\cong M_{\phi}$**

*Definition*:
If $S = R^{\phi} = \{r\in R: \phi(r)=r\}$, then $S$ is a subring of $R$ and if $M$ is an $R$-module, it is, by restriction of scalars, also an $S$-module. Now for any $S$-submodule $N$ of $M$, there is a natural a natural map of $R$-modules $e_N\colon R\otimes_S N\to M$, and we say that $N$ is an $S$-*lattice* for $M$ is this map is an isomorphism.

Now by construction, for any $S$-module $P$, $\phi$ induces an automorphissm of $P_R:=R\otimes_S P$ given by $\phi\otimes \text{id}_P$, where $(\phi\otimes \text{id}_P)((r\otimes p)=\phi(r)\otimes p$, for all $p \in P, r\in R$, and clearly this map gives an isomorphism between $(R\otimes_S P)$ and $(R\otimes_S P)_{\phi}$. Indeed if $\theta\colon P \to P$ is any isomorphism of $S$-modules, then $\phi\otimes \theta$ gives an isomorphism between $P_R$ and $(P_R)_{\phi}$. In particular, if $N$ is an $S$-lattice for an $R$-module $M$ and $\theta$ is any automorphism of $N$ as an $S$-module, then $T_{\phi,\theta}=e_N\circ (\phi\otimes \theta)\circ e_N^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $M$ to $M_{\phi}$. This generalizes the case where $M$ is a free $R$-module since if $B$ is an $R$-basis for $M$, if $R_1$ is *any* subring of $R$ and we let $N=R_1.B$ then $N$ is an $R_1$-lattice for $M$. When $R_1=S$ the map $T$ constructed above is just $T_{\phi,\text{id}_N}$ for this lattice.

**Group algebras**

A more substantial class of examples is given by the group algebra construction: If $G$ is a (finite) group and $\mathsf k$ is a field, then the group algebra $\mathsf k[G]$ is the vector space of functions $f\colon G\to \mathsf k$ equipped with the convolution product, so that
$$
f_1 * f_2(g) = \sum_{h \in G} f_1(gh^{-1})f_2(h)
$$
In terms of the obvious basis $\{e_g: g\in G\}$ given by the indictator functions of the elements, $e_{g_1}* e_{g_2} = e_{g_1g_2}$, and hence this construction is sometimes presented as taking formal linear combinations of the elements of $G$ and extending the group operation linearly.

For group algebras $\mathsf k[G]$ there are two kinds of automorphisms often considered.

1. The first arise from $\text{Aut}(G)$ -- if $\theta\colon G\to G$ is an isomorphism, then $\theta^*\colon \mathsf k[G]\to \mathsf k[G]$ given by $\theta^*(f)(g) = f(\theta^{-1}(g))$ is an isomorphism of rings (with inverse $(\theta^{-1})^*$) where
   $$
   \theta^{-1}(e_g)(h) = e_g \circ \theta^{-1}(h) = \delta_{g,\theta^{-1}(h)} = \delta_{\theta(g),h} = e_{\theta(g)}(h), \quad \forall g,h \in G. 
   $$
   so that in terms of the standard basis $\{e_g: g\in G\}$ the automorphism $\theta^*$ acts as $\theta^*(e_g) = e_{\theta(g)}$.
2. The second kind of automorphism comes from an automorphism of the field $\mathsf k$, where if $\lambda \colon \mathsf k \to \mathsf k$ and $f \in \mathsf k[G]$ then $\lambda_*(f) = \lambda\circ f$. The map $\lambda_*$ acts trivially on the basis $\{e_g: g\in G\}$, indeed $\lambda_*(\sum_{g \in G} a_g.e_g) = \sum_{g \in G} \lambda(a_g).e_g$.

For simplicity, lets fix $\mathsf k = \mathbb C$ (which is, in particular, algebraically closed of characteristic zero). Modules for $\mathbb C[G]$ are then semisimple, and so the question of which modules are isomorphic to their twists by an automorphism of $\mathbb C[G]$ reduces to the same question for simple modules.

In the case where $G$ is abelian then its irreducible representations are all $1$-dimensional, and there are $|G|$ of them (up to isomorphism). Moreover the tensor product makes the set of isomorphism classes of irreducibles $\hat{G}$, into a group, and $G\cong \hat{G}$. (To see this, note that any finite abelian group is a product of cyclic groups, hence it suffices to show this for cyclic groups, for which the result is easy to verify.) It follows that exactly $|G^\phi|$ irreducible representations of $G$ will be isomorphic to their twists by $\phi$.

An example where $\phi$ is of the second kind described above is when $\phi$ is induced complex conjugation. Now if $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space, if $G$ is a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, then there is an Hermitian inner product on $V$ which is invariant under the action of $G$. Now an Hermitian inner product gives an isomorphism $h\colon \overline{V} \to V^*$, where $\overline{V}$ denotes the vector space obtained by twisting the action of $\mathbb C$ by complex conjugation. Indeed if we assume our inner product is linear in the first variable and conjugate-linear in the second, then $h(v_0)(v):= \langle v,v_0\rangle$. If the inner product is $G$-invariant, then it is easy to see that $h$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb C[G]$-modules, and hence we see that, for any $\mathbb C[G]$-module $V$, its twist $V_{\phi}$ is always isomorphic to $V^*$, and thus $V\cong V_{\phi}$ if and only if $V\cong V^*$.

Now $V\cong V^*$ if and only if the corresponding characters, $\chi_V$ and $\chi_{V^*}$ are equal, and $\chi_{V^*}(g) = \chi(g^{-1}) = \overline{\chi(g)}$ (where the first equality follows from the definition of the action of $G$ on $V^{-1}$ and the second from the fact that if $A\in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ has finite order, then $A$ is diagonalizable and has eigenvalues which are roots of unity).

Thus we see that an irreducible representation $V$ is isomorphic to $V_{\phi}$ if and only if its character is real-valued. Now it is well-known that if the character of $V$ is real-valued, it need *not* be the case that there is a real representation $W_{\mathbb R}$ of $G$, that is, an $\mathbb R[G]$-module $W_\mathbb R$ such that $V \cong \mathbb C[G]\otimes_{\mathbb R[G]} W_{\mathbb R}$. This shows that the sufficient condition that a module contain a lattice for $S=R^{\phi}$ is not necessary.

*Example*: An explicit example of this is given by:

$$
G = \{ \pm I_2, \pm \left(\begin{array}{cc} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{array}\right), \pm\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right) ,\pm\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & i \\ i & -0 \end{array}\right) \} \subset \mathbb H = \{\left(\begin{array}{cc} z & -\bar{w} \\ w & \bar{z} \end{array}\right) \mid z,w \in \mathbb C\}
$$

then $G$ is a group of order $8$, and the embedding $G \subset \mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C)$ yields a $2$-dimensional representation $V$ of $G$ which is easily seen to be irreducible and have character $\chi_V$ where $\chi_V$ vanishes on all elements other than $\pm I_2$, and $\chi_V(\pm I_2) = \pm 2$. In  particular, $\chi_V$ is real-valued, so that $V\cong V_{\phi}$. But if there were a representation $W_{\mathbb R}$ of $\mathbb R[G]$ for which $V\cong \mathbb C[G]\otimes_{\mathbb R[G]} W_{\mathbb R}$, then $W_{\mathbb R}$ must be a faithful $2$-dimensional simple $\mathbb R[G]$-module, and moreover there must be an inner product on $W_{\mathbb R}$ which is invariant for the action of  $G$, that is, $G$ must be a subgroup of $\mathrm{O}(W_{\mathbb R})$. Now $\mathrm{SO}(W_{\mathbb R})$ is abelian, thus $G$ must contain a reflection (since any element of $\mathrm{O}(W_{\mathbb R})$ not in $\mathrm{SO}(W_{\mathbb R})$ is a reflection) and hence $C(W_{\mathbb R}) :=\mathrm{End}_G(W_{\mathbb R}) \cong \mathbb R$. Indeed any element of $C(W_{\mathbb R})$ must commutate with every element of $G$, and hence preserve their eigenspaces. Since $G$ contains a reflection, it contains an element with distinct real eigenvalues, and hence two distinct eigenlines $L_1$ and $L_2$, so that $C(W_{\mathbb R})\subseteq \mathrm{End}(L_1)\oplus \mathrm{End}(L_2) \cong \mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R$. It follows from Schur's Lemma that $C(W_{\mathbb R}) \cong \mathbb R$.

But now we may view $V$ as a $4$-dimensional *real* representation simply via the inclusion $\mathbb R[G]\hookrightarrow \mathbb C[G]$, and if $V = \mathbb C[G]\otimes_{\mathbb R[G]}W_{\mathbb R}$, then as an $\mathbb R[G]$-module, we would have $V\cong W_{\mathbb R}^{\oplus 2}$, and hence $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb R[G]}(V) \cong \mathrm{End}(\mathbb R^2)$. But $\mathbb H$ is a $4$-dimensional $\mathbb R$-subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C)$ which is isomorphic to $V$ via the map sending a matrix to its first column. (This map is an isomorphism on $\mathbb H$ because the second column of an element of $\mathbb H$ is clearly determined by the first column.) Moreover, this map is equivariant for the action of $G$, hence to compute $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb R[G]}(V)$ we may instead compute $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb R[G]}(\mathbb H)$. But if $h\in \mathbb H$, then *right-multiplication* by $h$ commutes with the action of $G$, and hence we get an injection map $\mathbb H^{\text{op}} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb R[G]}(V)= \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb R[G]}(\mathbb H)$. Since $\mathbb H^{\text{op}}$ is a 4-dimensional real division algebra, it is not isomorphic to (a subalgebra of) $\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb R)$, and thus $V$ does not arise as the complexification of a module for $\mathbb R[G]$ as claimed.